# apache2 Creating multiple sites under same domain name in https

Tags: networking, server, apache2

I want to have two sites that use the same domain name and what separates them is a slash in the URL.

For example:

1. www.mywebsite.com:443/site1          => `/var/www/mywebsite1`
2. www.mywebsite.com:443/site2       => `/var/www/mywebsite2`

How can I achieve this in apache2 on port 443?
i already have https setted up on something like this:
 1. www.mywebsite.com:443/          => `/var/www/mywebsite1`

Answer (score 0):

If you want exactly this, you should store `mywebsite2` inside `mywebside1` like this:

`/var/www/mywebsite1/site2`

To connect to web that use 443 with ssl you should go to:

`https://www.mywebsite.com/site1`

If you don't put https or http like you did, it use http that use port 80.

Check next link to edit the root directory of apache to `/var/www` or put all inside `/var/www/mywebsite1` that is probably your root directory. Will look like:

`/var/www/mywebsite1/site1`

`/var/www/mywebsite1/site2`

or set root directory to `/var/www` and should look like

`/var/www/site1`

`/var/www/site2`
https://www.tecmint.com/change-root-directory-of-apache-web-server/

Comment: i edited the question.